# Proper Rails Association for this setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Just starting out with rails and I have a question. My grasp on associations is weak.

Lets say I have a model **Cars**

some cars will be rentals and some will not. So I created a table and a model called **Rentals**

which just has the **car_id** in it, designating that at car_id is a rental.

Right now I have a **belong_to :cars** line in my Rental model. And I'm not sure that's right. I am attempting to get a list of all the rentals easily. So grabbing the car_ids from the rental table and getting all the car information from the cars table the most efficient way.

Can someone help out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following:

```
Car.joins(:rentals).all # try with :rental if not working
```

Will output all the cars that have a rental object associated with ;)

Comment: I knew there was a simple one liner. Thanks that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you will exactly need to do with it.

For simplicity, this is how I would do it.

```
class CarType #better than Rentals and more meaningful [:type => [rental, lease, own]]
  belongs_to :car
end

class Car
  has_one :car_type
end
```

So, now for the `cars` table, it will have a `car_type_id` pointing to the type in `car_types` table.

Comment: Wish I can accept two answers. the has_one was the other part of my issue. Put that in and with MrYoshijis answer below it is working well now.

Comment: @D3mon-1stVFW, it should be `belongs_to :car`